# MongoDB find() not getting anything

Tags: mongodb, syntax

I have a collection as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"),
    "date" : "20180126",
    "oid" : "000",
    "aid" : "0000000000",
    "currentavalible" : "7",
    "deletedbyuser" : "0",
    "reply" : [
        {
            "oidaid" : "000000",
            "nickname" : "****",
            "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
            "recomm" : "13",
            "unrecomm" : "0",
            "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
        }, 
        {
            "oidaid" : "000088",
            "nickname" : "para****",
            "date" : "2018-01-26 08:29:54",
            "recomm" : "12",
            "unrecomm" : "0",
            "contents" : "bbbbbb"
        }
    ]
}
```

To find in `reply` that  `"recomm"` is `"13"` i tried:

```
db.comments.find( { 'reply.recomm' : '13' })
db.comments.find( { 'reply' :{ 'recomm' : '13'}  })
db.comments.find( {'_id' :  ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"), 'reply.recomm' : '12' })
db.comments.find( {'_id' :  ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"), 'reply' : { 'recomm' : '12'} })
```

And all fetched me nothing.

What seems to be the error in my syntax?

Comment: db.collection.find() , A cursor to the documents that match the query criteria. When the find() method “returns documents,” the method is actually returning a cursor to the documents.

Comment: Use the $match(aggregation) pipeline .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.comments.find( { 'reply.recomm' : '13' })
db.comments.find( {'_id' :  ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"), 'reply.recomm' : '12' })
```

Both above query is looks fine and will be fetch the documents of records inside the comments collections.

I am sure that you are doing mistake something like not in the tree of particular database  where your `comments` collection reside.

Let's from beginning see here,

First i have create the **StackExchange** database.

```
>Use StackExchange
```

Then i have created the **comments** collection inside the `StackExchange` database.

```
> use StackExchange
switched to db StackExchange
>

> db.createCollection("comments")
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

And inside of comments collections i have insert the documents, which you have provided in souce code.

```
> db.comments.insert({
...     "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"),
...     "date" : "20180126",
...     "oid" : "000",
...     "aid" : "0000000000",
...     "currentavalible" : "7",
...     "deletedbyuser" : "0",
...     "reply" : [
...         {
...             "oidaid" : "000000",
...             "nickname" : "****",
...             "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
...             "recomm" : "13",
...             "unrecomm" : "0",
...             "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
...         },
...         {
...             "oidaid" : "000088",
...             "nickname" : "para****",
...             "date" : "2018-01-26 08:29:54",
...             "recomm" : "12",
...             "unrecomm" : "0",
...             "contents" : "bbbbbb"
...         }
...     ]
... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Now i want to fetch comments `documents` records from the `comments` collection, which is in `StackExchange` database.
First check through `mongo shell`, what is your current database like that

```
> db
StackExchange
>
```

Here it mongo shell the current database is `StackExchange`.

```
Note:- I have create comments collection in StackExchange database. But for your confirmation , you must always checks before queering the query in mongo shell like
```

> show collections
>   comments

Then try to find the documents inside the collection through the `db.collection.find()`.

> Note:- Here collection is the collection name. In your case it's
>   comments.

From the first query **db.comments.find( { 'reply.recomm' : '13' })**

```
> db.comments.find( { 'reply.recomm' : '13' }).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"),
        "date" : "20180126",
        "oid" : "000",
        "aid" : "0000000000",
        "currentavalible" : "7",
        "deletedbyuser" : "0",
        "reply" : [
                {
                        "oidaid" : "000000",
                        "nickname" : "****",
                        "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
                        "recomm" : "13",
                        "unrecomm" : "0",
                        "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
                },
                {
                        "oidaid" : "000088",
                        "nickname" : "para****",
                        "date" : "2018-01-26 08:29:54",
                        "recomm" : "12",
                        "unrecomm" : "0",
                        "contents" : "bbbbbb"
                }
        ]
}
```

and from the query
 **db.comments.find( {'_id' :  ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"), 'reply.recomm' : '12' })**

```
> db.comments.find( {'_id' :  ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"), 'reply.recomm' : '12' }).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"),
        "date" : "20180126",
        "oid" : "000",
        "aid" : "0000000000",
        "currentavalible" : "7",
        "deletedbyuser" : "0",
        "reply" : [
                {
                        "oidaid" : "000000",
                        "nickname" : "****",
                        "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
                        "recomm" : "13",
                        "unrecomm" : "0",
                        "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
                },
                {
                        "oidaid" : "000088",
                        "nickname" : "para****",
                        "date" : "2018-01-26 08:29:54",
                        "recomm" : "12",
                        "unrecomm" : "0",
                        "contents" : "bbbbbb"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

But from the mention below both query you shall not fetch the documents records from the comments collection due to their improper fetching of Array records.

```
db.comments.find( { 'reply' :{ 'recomm' : '13'}  })

db.comments.find( {'_id' :  ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"), 'reply' : { 'recomm' : '12'} })
```

As per MongoDB 3.6 Documented [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) . If you want to fetch the array documents then you can use **$ (projection)**, Or you can use [Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

As you said **only** you want to `find` the records in reply that  "recomm" is `13`.
so, you have to use  [`$elemMatch (projection)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)operator and your query will be as mention below

```
> db.comments.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0")},{reply: {$elemMatch: {recomm: "13"}}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"),
        "reply" : [
                {
                        "oidaid" : "000000",
                        "nickname" : "****",
                        "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
                        "recomm" : "13",
                        "unrecomm" : "0",
                        "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

After the **OP requirement** to **edit** the code and execute the query to find out OP desire results.

Here i want to insert the second documents which having different `id` field records in comments documents.

```
> db.comments.insert({
... ...     "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf1"),
... ...     "date" : "20180126",
... ...     "oid" : "000",
... ...     "aid" : "0000000000",
... ...     "currentavalible" : "7",
... ...     "deletedbyuser" : "0",
... ...     "reply" : [
... ...         {
... ...             "oidaid" : "000000",
... ...             "nickname" : "****",
... ...             "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
... ...             "recomm" : "13",
... ...             "unrecomm" : "0",
... ...             "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
... ...         },
... ...         {
... ...             "oidaid" : "000088",
... ...             "nickname" : "para****",
... ...             "date" : "2018-01-26 08:29:54",
... ...             "recomm" : "12",
... ...             "unrecomm" : "0",
... ...             "contents" : "bbbbbb"
... ...         }
... ...     ]
... ... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Now i only find out the `comments` collection documents , which having the "recomm":"13" records.

```
> db.comments.find({},{reply: {$elemMatch: {recomm: "13"}}}).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"),
        "reply" : [
                {
                        "oidaid" : "000000",
                        "nickname" : "****",
                        "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
                        "recomm" : "13",
                        "unrecomm" : "0",
                        "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf1"),
        "reply" : [
                {
                        "oidaid" : "000000",
                        "nickname" : "****",
                        "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45",
                        "recomm" : "13",
                        "unrecomm" : "0",
                        "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I perfectly understood! Can you answer me one last question? What should I do to not only search in    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0") this object but all objects in db.comments?

Comment: @Arthur Park, If you want to use 'id' field and you want to search all documents in your 'comments' collection then simple query like "db.comments.find().pretty()". It will search all documents in your comments collection.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question, but I meant if i am to search with `db.comments.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0")},{reply: {$elemMatch: {recomm: "13"}}})`, It will search from object `5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0` only. What should I do to search `recomm: "13"`  to all object in collection? I am literally digging into the documentation but I can't understand it :(

Comment: @ArthurPark, Then simple execute the query like db.comments.find({},{reply: {$elemMatch: {recomm: "13"}}}).pretty()

Comment: Thanks so much I was digging out literaly everywhere to find answers.

Comment: @ArthurPark,Always Welcome in StackExchange site.

Comment: So sorry one last question, so if  $elemMatch is for a complete match, then what is for partial match?  `db.comments.find({},{reply: {$text: {contents: "aaa"}}}).pretty()` and `db.comments.find({},{reply: {$text: {$search: "aaa"}}}).pretty()` but it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find error.. I inserted that same document to test.comments and firing your query gave right answer.

```
db.comments.find({'reply.recomm':'13'})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a6d9a1ee183f06dfd91dbf0"), "date" : "20180126", "oid" : "000", "aid" : "0000000000", "currentavalible" : "7", "deletedbyuser" : "0", "reply" : [ { "oidaid" : "000000", "nickname" : "****", "date" : "2018-01-26 07:32:45", "recomm" : "13", "unrecomm" : "0", "contents" : "aaaaaaaaaaaa" }, { "oidaid" : "000088", "nickname" : "para****", "date" : "2018-01-26 08:29:54", "recomm" : "12", "unrecomm" : "0", "contents" : "bbbbbb" } ] }
```

Are you sure that you were in the right database?

So `db` command gives right DB name. Or `db.comments.find()` gives you all documents from your `comments` collection.

Comment: I did the queries to get  ` "recomm" : "13"` . but it gave all `12` and `13`

Comment: @Arthur Park, I have replied for that, if you want to fetch only the records of " recomm": "13" the use the "$elemMatch (projection)" operator. Which only fetch the records based on their condition.